# Is there a way to get the current window size in iTerm?

Tags: macos, iterm2

I'm trying to create an iTerm action to paste the current window width into the current session.  My first attempt just used a python coprocess to run a shell command, but not surprisingly, it always returns the default size of 80 -- presumably it is creating a new session that it reports on.  So I think this will require a native iTerm API call rather than a shell command.

Comment: Try this; `$ echo "tty has $(tput cols)/$(tput lines) columns/lines."` - if "iterm" uses terminfo / ncurses.

Comment: That doesn't work.  I get "No value for $TERM and no -T specified".  As I mentioned, I don't think a shell command would work here because it would be run as a separate process and not in the terminal window in question.

Comment: All commands run with the terminal window has stdin/stdout/stderr connected to the current "tty" unless you redirect any of them, regardless of subshell or not. IMO an unset $TERM is an error, and at least one possible cause for the above to not work, may be there is more settings required though.

Answer (score 0):

If launched as a separate process you could use AppleScript to get the window dimensions of your terminal window:

```sh
osascript -e 'tell application "iterm" to get the bounds of window 1'
```

Alternatively:

```sh
osascript -e 'tell application "iterm" to get the bounds of front window'
```

Docs: https://macosxautomation.com/applescript/firsttutorial/11.html

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately, "bounds" returns the window coordinates in window dimensions.  But it does not return the character width of the window.

Comment: @CeneC You asked for "window size", not character width.

Comment: Fair enough.  But I did mean to ask for character width.